# Pandas not populating Column based on Condition

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pandas-datareader

Experts,

I am having an issue with Pandas ..

Not sure why the below condition is not being satisfied.

```
df = pd.read_csv(path + filename, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
for i in range(1, len(signal)):

    if [(df['x'] < 2) & (df['y'] <= 0)]:
        listLongShort1.append("A_Condition")

# The other way around
    elif [(df['x'] > 3) & (df['y'] >= 1)]:
        listLongShort1.append("B_Condition")

    else:
        listLongShort1.append("No Condition")
```

It is just printing populating column with "A_Condition", for some reason not seeing elif or else.

Can you please advise what is wrong with my code ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is a bitwise operator.
`AND` is a operator you want to use to check conditions.

```
if ((df['x'] < 2) and (df['y'] <= 0)):
    listLongShort1.append("A_Condition")
elif ((df['x'] > 3) and (df['y'] >= 1)):
    listLongShort1.append("B_Condition")
else:
    listLongShort1.append("No Condition")
```

Comment: Correction: `AND` is not the correct keyword in python, it's `and`.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` conditions in python are statements, so the usage is:

```
if expression-here :
    # your body
```

Example:

```
if (df['x'] < 2) and (df['y'] <= 0):
    # whatever you want to do.
```

From what you've done, the expression is inside a list (`[]`) and it's value is always `True` or `False`, so the expression inside the list is always a boolean and thus is always a list of one element, which is a `True` in `if` condition of python.

That is:

```
if [False]: # always true
    # always get's executed
```

or

```
if [True]: # always true
    # always get's executed
```

Only case where the list passes as false is when it's empty, i.e.:

```
if []: # always false
    # doesn't get executed
```

But since that's not possible in your case, you're facing an always "truth" case.